# Can we use list of database_version for google_sql_database_instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform-provider-gcp

I want to use some database_flag in sql db instance the issue is that these are depends upon database_version of sql instance So to resolve it can we use list of database_version as needed flags on multiple versions like sql,psql,sqlserver

I want to create sql database instance using terraform gcp

Answer (score 0):

No, we cannot create it. it is not feasible.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35313519)

Comment: @user16217248 how is this not an answer? it would definitely benefit greatly from elaboration on why, and it clearly isn't a great answer because it's lacking that, but how is it _not_ an answer?